# how to find max number in 2d array in prolog?

Tags: multidimensional-array, prolog

For example, I have 2d array in prolog like this:

```
[1 ,2 ,3].
[4 ,1 ,3].
[1 ,3 ,4].
```

How to find max number in this 2d array? (which is '4')

(So I can write some code that check if max is an even or odd number and return 'true'/'false' for my prolog function)

Comment: First you need to tell us how you are representing the 2d array. What are the predicates you have defined so far? What have you tried?

Comment: Usually, to find the maximum, you take the first element, and then you keep on comparing with the next element, keeping the larger one. Once you are out of elements you know you have your maximum.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you represent a matrix as a list of list, and you have a predicate to get the max of a list (here, I use `max_list/2` from SWI-Prolog), you can do it like this:

```
max_matrix(L, M) :-
    maplist(max_list, L, Ms),
    max_list(Ms, M).
```

Edge cases and other quirks are left for you…